# What is the best way to add a comment policy to the comment form?

Tags: 7, comments, i18n-l10n

Surely this is a common use-case... I would have thought? Underneath "Add new comment" heading I would like to add a block of text like "Comments are pre-moderated and may be edited before publication". I have an internationalised site so the text must be translatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with a form_alter hook.

```
<?php
function MODULENAME_form_comment_node_NODE_TYPE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    //drupal_set_message('<pre>'.print_r($form, 1).'</pre>');
    $form['privacy-note'] = array(
          '#markup' => t('Comments are pre-moderated and may be edited before publication');

        );
}
```

Yes it sounds a little silly to make a module for this. But making a little module for every little work is also not a smart option. 
If you have never created a module before, See this: http://drupal.org/node/1074360
Don't forget to change MODULENAME and NODE_TYPE with actual values. if you have any questions, I'd be happy to answer them here :)

Comment: Thanks, it's working, however the order is wrong. How do I get the privacy-note to appear first - before anything else in the form?

Comment: Don't worry, I figured it out. Use the 'weight' property.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do it.

Option 1

Implement [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) in your custom module.

Option 2

Use the [markup](http://drupal.org/project/markup) module.